# JComboBox setBackground() without changing the color of the arrow

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to figure this out for 6 hours now. I finally got the colors to change as desired, but I just want to keep the default color for the arrow of the combobox.

Here is the code...

**Note:** Edited code to compile without background shown in pictures...

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxButton;

public class TestGui extends JFrame {
    private final String[] guiCharSelDefault = {"---  Select Character ---"};
    private final String[] characters = {"SelectedTextOne", "SelectedTextTwo", "SelectedTextThree", "SelectedTextFour"};
    private final String[] guiCharSel = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(guiCharSelDefault, characters);
    private JComboBox charCombo = createStandardCombo(guiCharSel);
    private JPanel topFrame = createTopFrame();
    private JScrollPane topFrameScroll = createTopScrollPane();
    private JPanel centerFrame = createCenterFrame();

    //**************************************************************************************
    // Constructor

    TestGui(){
        add(topFrameScroll, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    //**************************************************************************************
    // Support Methods
    private static GridBagConstraints setGbc(int gridx, int gridy, int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int ipadx, int ipady, String anchorLocation, double weightx, double weighty, Insets insets){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("WEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("EAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        } else {
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        }

        gbc.gridx = gridx; // column
        gbc.gridy = gridy; // row
        gbc.gridwidth = gridWidth; // number of columns
        gbc.gridheight = gridHeight; // number of rows
        gbc.ipadx = ipadx; // width of object
        gbc.ipady = ipady; // height of object
        gbc.weightx = weightx; // shifts rows to side of set anchor
        gbc.weighty = weighty; // shifts columns to side of set anchor
        gbc.insets = insets; // placement inside cell
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

        return gbc;
    }

    private Insets setInsets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right){
        Insets insets = new Insets(top,left,bottom,right);
        return insets;
    }

    //**************************************************************************************
    // Interactive Object Methods

    private JComboBox createStandardCombo(String[] defaultValues){
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(defaultValues);
        ComboBoxRenderer cbr = new ComboBoxRenderer();
        DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
        dlcr.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        comboBox.setRenderer(cbr);
        comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("X" + guiCharSelDefault + "X");
        return comboBox;
    }

    //**************************************************************************************
    // Object Action Methods

    private void setComboBoxColorBackgroundWithMetalArrow(Color color){
        int componentCount = charCombo.getComponentCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < componentCount; i++) {
            Component component = charCombo.getComponent(i);
            if (component instanceof MetalComboBoxButton) {
                MetalComboBoxButton metalComboBoxButton =
                        (MetalComboBoxButton) component;
                Icon comboIcon = metalComboBoxButton.getComboIcon();
                BufferedImage bufferedImage =
                        new BufferedImage(
                                comboIcon.getIconWidth(),
                                comboIcon.getIconHeight(),
                                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                comboIcon.paintIcon(
                        metalComboBoxButton, bufferedImage.getGraphics(), 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setCharComboAction(){
        charCombo.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String charName = ((JComboBox)(e.getSource())).getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (!(charName.equals(guiCharSelDefault[0]))){
                            DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
                            DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(characters);
                            model.setSelectedItem(charName);
                            charCombo.setModel(model);
                            if (charName.equals("SelectedTextOne")){
                                //charCombo.getEditor().getEditorComponent().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                                charCombo.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            } else if (charName.equals("SelectedTextTwo")){
                                charCombo.setBackground(Color.RED);
                            } else {
                                charCombo.setBackground(dlcr.getBackground());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    //**************************************************************************************
    // Panel Methods

    private JPanel createTopFrame(){
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

        pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        setCharComboAction();
        pnl.add(charCombo, setGbc(0,0, 1,1, 0,0, "WEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        pnl.add(button, setGbc(0,1, 1,1, 0,0, "WEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));

        pnl.setOpaque(false);
        return pnl;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTopScrollPane(){
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, new Color(224,224,224));
        Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compoundSetup = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, lineBorder);
        Border compoundFinal = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(compoundSetup, loweredBevel);

        scrollPane.setBorder(compoundFinal);
        scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setView(topFrame);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createCenterFrame() {
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Color lineColor = new Color(224, 224, 224);
        Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(5, 5, 5, 5, lineColor);
        Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compoundSetup = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, lineBorder);
        Border compoundFinal = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(compoundSetup, loweredBevel);
        TitledBorder topFrameTitle = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(compoundFinal, "Stuff");
        topFrameTitle.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);

        pnl.setBorder(topFrameTitle);
        pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        pnl.setOpaque(false);
        return pnl;
    }

    //**************************************************************************************

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestGui();
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am using a custom renderer. Here is the code for that...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ComboBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer
{
    private Color selectionBackgroundColor;
    private DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

    // Constructor
    public ComboBoxRenderer()
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
        selectionBackgroundColor = this.dlcr.getBackground(); // Have to set a color, else a compiler error will occur
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        // Set the list background color to default color (default color will show once selection is made)
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        Color mouseHoverHighlight = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        setText((String)value);

        // Check which item is selected
        if(isSelected)
        {
            // Set background color of the item your cursor is hovering over to the original background color
            setBackground(mouseHoverHighlight);
        }
        else
        {
            // Set background to specific color depending on text value
            String selectedTextInDropdownList = getText();
            if (selectedTextInDropdownList.equals("SelectedTextOne")) {
                setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (selectedTextInDropdownList.equals("SelectedTextTwo")) {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                setBackground(this.dlcr.getBackground());
            }
        }
        String selectedText = getText();
        if (selectedText.equals("SelectedTextOne")){
            list.setSelectionBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if (selectedText.equals("SelectedTextTwo")){
            list.setSelectionBackground(Color.RED);
        } else {
            list.setSelectionBackground(this.dlcr.getBackground());
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce error:**

[image]

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: Can you describe a little better what the behavior you're looking for is? I get that you don't want the arrow to change color, but what are you actually trying to do? Also, it would be nice if you could edit the program so we can run it more easily. I was able to get it running by deleting some of the code, like the references to `BackgroundPanel`, but it's nice for us if we can just paste it in to an editor. (I'm on a Mac though, unfortunately, so I can't actually help with the issue you're having. Mac doesn't color the arrow because they have a more specific sort of style to the LAF.)

Comment: Actually, I think I was able to reproduce it with the metal LAF. Is there a reason that you want the calls to `charCombo.setBackground(...)` in the action performed method? The color from the renderer should show through, so I don't think you need to set the background on the combo box itself. Setting the background on the combo box seems to be what changes the arrow color.

Comment: *"Is there a reason that you want the calls to charCombo.setBackground(...) in the action performed method?"*. Yup, the reason is listed here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646234/custom-jcomboboxrenderer-change-background-color-depending-on-text-selection

Comment: Also, sorry about the background, this is test code I like to try and copy/past on stack overflow. I'll remove that part as it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but BasicComboBoxUI put a spoke in your wheel. Fortunately I have a trick for you, which helps to avoid this problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ComboBgTest {

    private static final String[] VALUES = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(VALUES);
        cb.setSelectedItem(null);
        cb.setRenderer(new BasicComboBoxRenderer() {
            boolean ignoreBG = true;
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean cellHasFocus) {
                ignoreBG = false;
                Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if (index == -1) { // check whether we are render the item shown at top
                    if (VALUES[0].equals(value)) {
                        c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    } else if (VALUES[1].equals(value)) {
                        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    } else if (VALUES[2].equals(value)) {
                        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
                ignoreBG = true;
                return this;
            }

            @Override
            public void setBackground(Color bg) {
                // ignore all BG which is set from outside.
                if (!ignoreBG) {
                    super.setBackground(bg);
                }
            }
        });
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Combo test");
        frm.add(cb);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

P.S. The same approach works also for font and foregorund.

Comment: had to change line `JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(VALUES);` to `JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(VALUES);`. Other than that, it seems to be working. I'll dissect it later when I'm done with my current task to use the same logic. Thanks :)

Comment: @FiddleFreak probably you use a very old java version. This code was compiled and tested with Java 7.

Comment: Opps, just released we're using the same basic solution :P

Comment: Using java 8, also the issue with this solution is it adds the highlight selected (removing the background color), and removes the colors in the dropdown list. Trying different things... (seems to change behavior based upon when ignoreBG is changed, just need to get the right combination)

Comment: @FiddleFreak You can remove the line `if (index == -1) {` and the corresponded closing brace. In this case coloring will work also for the drop-down list

Comment: So I got the behavior exactly how I want it (posted here - https://gist.github.com/vardahoth/745d16c1fb632c6a5c88b4fbc638a774). The selection box is not highlighted. The drop down list highlights grey when hovering your mouse over the item (while keeping all items at their respected color). Selecting the item does not highlight, and keeps the respected color. And unselecting the combo box (by clicking the button) keeps the respected color. The TestGUI code in question should compile. There is only one problem I see.... `nextComment ran out of characters`

Comment: during the dropdown selection, it looks like it sets `setBackground()` is set to an infinite loop. This has to do with lines 44-51 (which I added to fix all issues) > https://gist.github.com/vardahoth/745d16c1fb632c6a5c88b4fbc638a774.

Comment: alright seemed to fix the infinit loop issue (just had to move the if/else block with `list.setSelectionBackground....` under the `if(isSelected){}` and before line `setBackground(mouseHoverHighlight);`. The only thing is I see two mini-lines above and below the color background in the box, but I suppose it's really not that big of a deal. Thanks for all the help and here is a copy of the code working > https://gist.github.com/vardahoth/745d16c1fb632c6a5c88b4fbc638a774

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is, the `JComboBox` is changing the background color of the selected item AFTER it's been selected (and rendered) from the list.  One possible solution is to simply circumvent this by having a "override" color which is always returned, regardless of what is set, for example...

[image: Background Changed][image: Background Changed]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestGui extends JFrame {

    private final String[] guiCharSel = {"---  Select Character ---", "SelectedTextOne", "SelectedTextTwo", "SelectedTextThree", "SelectedTextFour"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGui();
    }

    public TestGui() throws HeadlessException {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JComboBox box = new JComboBox(guiCharSel);
                box.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());

                JTextField field = new JTextField(10);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                frame.add(box, gbc);
                frame.add(field, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class ComboBoxRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        private Color overrideBackground;
        private Color mouseHoverHighlight = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

        // Constructor
        public ComboBoxRenderer() {
            setOpaque(true);
            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
            setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public void setOpaque(boolean isOpaque) {
            System.out.println("setOpaque " + isOpaque);
            //NOOP
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOpaque() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setBackground(Color bg) {
            System.out.println(">> Background = " + bg);
            super.setBackground(bg); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public Color getBackground() {
            return overrideBackground == null ? super.getBackground() : overrideBackground;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            // Set the list background color to default color (default color will show once selection is made)
            overrideBackground = null;
            setText((String) value);

            // Check which item is selected
            System.out.println(value + "; isSelected = " + isSelected + "; cellHasFocus = " + cellHasFocus);
            if (isSelected) {
                // Set background color of the item your cursor is hovering over to the original background color
                setBackground(mouseHoverHighlight);
            } else {
                // Set background to specific color depending on text value
                String selectedTextInDropdownList = getText();
                if (selectedTextInDropdownList.equals("SelectedTextOne")) {
                    System.out.println(">> Green");
                    overrideBackground = Color.GREEN;
                } else if (selectedTextInDropdownList.equals("SelectedTextTwo")) {
                    System.out.println(">> Red");
                    overrideBackground = Color.RED;
                } else {
                    overrideBackground = null;
                }
            }

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

This will only show up AFTER the combobox loses focus, as the item is been rendered as "selected".  You could muck around with change the selection background as well, but I couldn't find any decent combination of states where it was simple to do